# PHP get a Part of the URL

Tags: php

I want to fetch the value of until from following url,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/168820059842589/feed?fields=id,from,message,comments%7Bfrom,id,created_time,message,attachment,comments%7Bfrom,id,created_time,message,attachment%7D%7D,type,created_time,updated_time,picture,name,caption,link,source,description,likes,story,place,story_tags&limit=250&include_hidden=true&until=1394190620&__paging_token=enc_AeyIp_kAzWE_u3avDbSjlT69EtTXCEOSDLyp0xSOTptJHfmlHKARfuTm197SkZAPDhKsXAtfu9G7jqzn75ymXK60UwG3nR2itFLk-IhY_hdOzQ
```

Thanks

Comment: WHAT exactly do you want? What have you tried?

Comment: echo $_REQUEST['until'];

Comment: Tried following one 
$parsed_url =  parse_url($paging['next']);
$tmp = explode("&",$parsed_url['query']);
 echo $tmp[3];

Comment: Why to try this much complex when you can just use the inbuilt $_GET['until']

Comment: Above url is part of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/168820059842589/feed?fields=id,from,message,comments%7Bfrom,id,created_time,message,attachment,comments%7Bfrom,id,created_time,message,attachment%7D%7D,type,created_time,updated_time,picture,name,caption,link,source,description,likes,story,place,story_tags&limit=250&include_hidden=true&until=1394190620&__paging_token=enc_AeyIp_kAzWE_u3avDbSjlT69EtTXCEOSDLyp0xSOTptJHfmlHKARfuTm197SkZAPDhKsXAtfu9G7jqzn75ymXK60UwG3nR2itFLk-IhY_hdOzQ';
$arr = array();
parse_str($url,$arr);
echo $arr['until'];
//outputs 1394190620
```